# JavaFx TableView select multiple cells

Tags: java, javafx

I wanted to select multiple cells in tableview.
I have tried setting Multiple Selection mode.
and my selectCell mode is also enabled.
How can i allow user to select multiple cells.

Comment: Please include the relevant code you have tried in the question as well, and, if possible, describe in more detail the symptoms of how it fails.

Comment: I got the issue, in actual my columns are getting selected, i just have UI issue